# copy string function to non const char buffer

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to copy a string to buffer for further processing. I used the instruction

```
char *buf = line.c_str();
```

but `buf` type should be `const char*`, However If I'm going to use

```
const char *buf = line.c_str();
```

I'll face another problem as I'm using `strtok_s` function for processing the `buf`. this function expecting `char *` arg. rather than `const char*`. 
Is there another function or a way to copy this line to `char *` ??

Comment: You are not allowed to call `strtok` directly on the result of `.c_str()` because `strtok` modifies its argument/buffer. To use `strtok` on it, you must make a full copy first and use that.

Comment: `const char* buf = line.c_str();` is NOT a copy, you are simply getting the address of the string. That string is immutable, because it's owned by the std::string you're getting it from. You're going to need to either copy it someplace mutable - your own char[] buffer or a strdup buffer, or you're going to need to use std::string members to operate on the string directly instead.

(bear in mind that strtok actually modifies the source string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use standard library containers, such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or C++14's [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray):

```
std::vector<char> v(line.begin(), line.end());
```

Bear in mind that this copies `line`'s characters without the null termination `\0`. In this sense, the buffer does not represent a string. If you need null termination (which is not clear from the question), you have to add it manually:

```
v.push_back('\0');
```

Then you can use the underlying data via

```
char* c1 = &v[0]
char* c2 = v.data(); // c++11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
char* buf = strdup(line.c_str());
// use strtok_s however you need
free(buf);
```

You can't use the buffer directly without modifying it because strtok_s does actually modify the data. `c_str` wants you to leave the data alone.

If you don't care about the modifications, just do:

```
char* buf = &line[0];
```

Comment: +1 for `&line[0]`. -1 for `strdup(line.c_str())`. Final score - zero.